# FTPPutFile triguring firewall issues causing falure

Tags: c++, ftp, firewall, wininet

I'm quite inexperienced in C++, and i'm trying to make a project, that can simply upload files from client PC's, to my plainFTP server. However, i'm noting that by default windows firewall is blocking this communication (I tested on both a PC in our active directory and outside to same result).

This is my code

```
       void doUpload(char *LocFile, char *Rfile){

                //LocFile must come  with path e.g.  C:\\helloworld.txt
                //Rfile is the name of the file on the remote server. hi.txt
                char *user="<FTPUSER>";
                char *pass="<FTPPASS>";
                char *ftpserver="<FTPIP>";
                HINTERNET hInternet;
                HINTERNET hFtpSession;
                hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL,INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,NULL,NULL,0);
                hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet,ftpserver , INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, user, pass, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);
                //doupload
                if(FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, LocFile, Rfile,FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY,INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE)){
                    print("Upload Worked!");
                    Sleep(1000);
                    InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession);
                    InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
                }
                else{cout << "FAILED UPLOAD\n";cout << LocFile;cout << Rfile;}
            }
```

The LocFile is the local file to be uploaded, and Rfile is the name to give it on the FTP server.

Interestingly even if i enable it in the firewall it seems to fail, but my main question is, is there a way to do this that will bypass the firewall/use an already permitted handle and shall not cause me to have to mess with the firewall rules in group policy (Even this would be an issue, as some computers  are not in active directory)?

I know this is possibly with winsock, however in codeblocks i can't get winsock working, and i've never used it, and so would take more time than i have to code. If possible, i am looking for compatibility with windows XP up to 8.

EDIT:

I've added some more debug information, and the PC out of the Active directory is getting a timed out error, and my computer, in the AD is getting the following from internetgetlastmessage as error code 12 12003

```
  200 Switching to Binary mode.
  500 Illegal PORT command.
  500 Unknown command.
```

Comment: You are performing a *Passive mode* transfer. That is generally firewall-friendly, as it uses an outbound connection.  Firewalls tend to block inbound connections, not outbound connections, unless the firewall admin has configured a specific rule to block outbound connections.

Comment: Firewalls are designed to control communications and not to be bypassed.  So you'll experience similar variations of the same issue whatever socket API you'll use.

Comment: @RemyLebeau coporate security experts doing their job correcly usually disallow PC/PC communication and only allow PC/servers and PC/routing device.

Comment: That was the idea of using passive mode, so you're saying generally this shouldn't be triggering the firewall to block? And is there not a way i can make it use an existing open port? As it only needs to upload then it's done.

Comment: And @Cristophe the FTP server isn't PC to PC, the FTP is in the cloud.

Comment: You need to check the firewall's actual rules, make sure that FTP ports 20 and 21, and your app, are not being explicitly blocked.

Comment: Ok ! That's good news and bad news.  The cloud server has certainly a defined standard FTP port.  So you cannot try to missuse another port. And outbound connections are also more controlled than internals and frequently involve additional proxy settings.  But did you already test if the proble comes from your app or your code ?  Could you for example reach this server using the FTP command from the command line ?

Comment: The interesting thing here is that i have filezilla on both those PC's and i can connect fine to this server. Yet when i run the app, it brought the firewall up for me, and when i said allow, it blocked it anyway.

Comment: Could it be because windows firewall works by the app that runs it? IE would i be able to spoof being filezilla or cuteFTP or some such? I know it's crude.

Comment: I've edited the OP. with more info

Comment: Anyone got anymore ideas? Still stuck on this, i read that using winsock can bypass firewall, but i'm unsure how to do this? Why does this trip firewall, but winsock doesn't?